# Serving flask application with Nginx and gunicorn: permission denied when connecting to webpage.sock

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to setup a simple flask application served by Nginx and Gunicorn and have mostly followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04#configuring-nginx-to-proxy-requests). When trying to access the webpage, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.

The nginx log (`/var/log/nginx/error.log`) says :

`[crit] 23472#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/crawforc3/webpage/webpage.sock failed (13: Permission denied)`

I checked and there is a `webpage.sock` file in my project directory that looks like this:

`srwxrwxrwx 1 crawforc3 www-data     0 May 31 17:59 webpage.sock`

Here is my `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=crawforc3
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/crawforc3/webpage
Environment="PATH=home/crawforc3/miniconda3/envs/HALSWEBPAGE/bin"
ExecStart=/home/crawforc3/miniconda3/envs/HALSWEBPAGE/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/crawforc3/webpage/webpage.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that there was a discrepancy with `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

I had the user set as www-data and I should have set it as crawforc3. Making this change and restarting nginx and gunicorn resolved the issue.